# using react router for navigation with redirect getting a new page but without content

Tags: reactjs

Trying to use React Router to go up from a child component to parent. 
Using redirect from a sidebar component and a button

I've tried to specifically set state in as a prop to my redirect but when you run the code it isn't able to find my other component

```
HourlyWeather.js 

this.state = {
     redirect: false
}
```

then I'm using this for my handle submit for my button:

```
HourlyWeather.js
  handleSubmit = () => {
    this.setState({
      redirect: !this.state.redirect
    });
  };
  /*
```

This is my redirect:

```
 onst SwapToCurrent = ({ component: Component }) => {
  return (
    <Route
      render={props =>
        DisplayHourlyWeather.redirect === 'true' &&
        DisplayWeather.fetchedWeatherData === 'true' ? (
          <DisplayWeather {...props} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to={{
              pathname: '/current',
              state: { fetchedWeatherData: true }
            }}
          />
        )
      }
    />
  );
};
```

finally this is what I am trying to conditionally render:

```
if (this.state.fetchedWeatherData) {
      return (
        <div className="ui container">
          <br />
          <h1>Current temperature</h1>
```

When you click the button nothing happens the component doesn't get switched I feel like I am missing something related to this, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is all of this code in one file? Put file names above the code blocks please. Can we see your render or return block please.

Comment: Ok, so when you redirect the user to '/current', do you want to redirect to a whole new component? Or, do you just want to display the JSX "<div className="ui....".../>? Where is that last block of code, "if (this.state...) {}", in the same file? If you just want to render the "<div classNam.../>" block, then you don't need to redirect to a completely different component. I'm not seeing a <Route path="/current"/> in the code, so I'm assuming "/current" is handled in your App.js? We need to see how your switch/routes are being handled there. Post the render or your App.js please.